# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred vb.net 2013

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.IO
Imports Access

Public Class Form1
Dim AccessApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AccessApplication = New Access.Application()

    If Not AccessApplication.Visible = True Then
        AccessApplication.Visible = True
    End If

    AccessApplication.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\POS\POS.lib", False)

End Sub
End Class
```

I'm trying to open "C:\POS\POS.lib" from vb.net 2013, but the error 'System.AccessViolationException' appear, I tried a lot of methods to fix it but didn't works :
the error appear on the line

```
  AccessApplication.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\POS\POS.lib", False)
```

This is the full error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in PosStartup.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Here is the file logo:

[image]

Comment: And are you sure the `POS.lib` file is a correct MS Access Database ? cause usually it's *.accdb or *.mdb extensions...

Comment: I changed it from .accdb to .lib for a specific purpose, is there a way I can open "C:\POS\POS.lib" ?

Comment: Is your database password protected ? Maybe it is already opened in another application ? When you rename it back to .accdb, does it open ?

Comment: sorry it was .mde, and after renaming it to POS.mde the error still appear ! any suggestions ?

Comment: what happens when you double click on the file, in windows?

Comment: it open normally but there is a lock on the file .mde, I've added an image at the button of the post... how can i remove this lock ? or the problem is not from the lock ?

Comment: MDE file icon has a lock. If it's origionaly an mde file, it's just fine.

Comment: I can do everything... and the error  'System.AccessViolationException' still appear !

Comment: If you can edit forms and code, it is not mde file... is it mdb?

Comment: Is your database file password protected ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the original file extension, and rename the file to have this extension before you open it, and rename it to the have "lib" extension, after you close it. Use **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start** to start Access in a new process. System knows to open Access, according to file extension:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists ("C:\POS\POS.lib") And Not System.IO.File.Exists Then ("C:\POS\POS.mdb") ' replace 'mdb' with the correct file extension
    System.IO.File.Move("C:\POS\POS.lib", "C:\POS\POS.mdb")' replace 'mdb' with the correct file extension
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\POS\POS.mdb")' replace 'mdb' with the correct file extension
End If
```

Comment: thank you, but still same error with .lib .mde and .mdb !!

Comment: @Tony The *Access* in *System.AccessViolationException* tricked me to think the error was raised by *MS Access* or do to *MS Access* issues. It is totally a .net error, raised when accessing un-managed memory from from CLR managed app. My guess: The actual Access App allocates memory for it's use, or for the use of code running on execution. This memory is un-managed by CLR, and raises the error. I found with Google [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that Access, as all Office, is COM

Comment: @Tony, so this answer is actually totally useless... It's a **hard-core .net** issue.

Comment: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: hey Marlan, thank you very much for your help,
but is there any other method (or code) to open access file from vb.net ?

Comment: I usually do Access... What are you trying to do, retrieve data? run a method in Access? have Access opened for user use?

Comment: I need to open it with 
"AccessApplication.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\POS\POS.lib", False)" because I need to use the methods of AccessApplication...

Comment: Well, then see the links I brought above, and google for more about COM interop in .net. That seems to me like the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no need to manege Access from your VB.net app, remove all *Office.Interop*, and *Access* Namespaces objects, and use **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start** to start Access in a new process, and send the file to it as a parameter:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("Access.exe", "C:\POS\POS.lib")
```

Comment: @Tony, Please read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) about this method. Basically it should work like a double click.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `Interop.DLL_Name.dll` to `DLL_Name.dll` and reference it to project. Set Interop true.